# EOSlime TypeError: Contract.actionname is not a function

Tags: smart-contract, action, unit-tests

This is my test file:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const TOKEN_WASM_PATH = './contracts/group/group.wasm';
const TOKEN_ABI_PATH = './contracts/group/group.abi';

describe("EOSIO Group", function (eoslime) {

    this.timeout(15000);

    let groupContract;
        let groupTable;
        let adminAccount;

    before(async () => {
            adminAccount = await eoslime.Account.load('groupaccount','myPK','active');
    });

    before(async () => {
        groupContract = eoslime.Contract.at(TOKEN_ABI_PATH, 'group', adminAccount);
        groupTable = groupContract.groups;
    });

    it("Should create a new group", async () => {
             await groupContract.upsertgroup("group2", "Assistant", "normal user include all users", "Common", 1,{ from: adminAccount.name });
    });
```

It is giving error on `eoslime test`:

```
1) EOSIO Group
     UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Provided String is not an instance of BaseAccount
      Should create a new group:
    TypeError: groupContract.upsertgroup is not a function
     at Context.it (tests/example-tests.js:37:27)
```

Contract name is "group", it is deployed on the account which is loaded here in before(). So, I don't need to deploy it here again. Only access contract and call its actions. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on Github. The first problem was eoslime was not installed properly (locally). So, I changed the project directory and installed eoslime in that directory again.
Second, the changes in code.
Added:

```
const eoslime = require('eoslime').init();
```

Changed:

```
contract = await eoslime.Contract.at(CONTRACT_NAME,adminAccount)
```

It solves all errors.